# Firebase Realtime Database update multiple children without a common parent

Tags: ios, firebase

Let's say I want to update `/groups/$groupID` and `users/$userID` in the single update call. The update should fail if any of the update calls fail. I'm getting

> Listener at / failed: permission_denied

when trying to update via

```
ref().update({
'groups/...': 'value1',
'users/...': 'value2'
})
```

probably because I have no rules defined at the root / level, but separately in each child (separately in /groups, /users, etc.).

If I would, indeed, define a write rule at the root level, wouldn't that mean that all the child write rules are overridden by it? I wouldn't want that to happen. I've looked into transaction API and it seems that the transactions are ran 'on a reference', which in this case would also be the root reference.

Is there a different way of running a transaction that runs multiple updates?

Comment: Are you sure the rules for the individual groups are allowing the operation? With the web SDK, what you are describing it's possible. Not sure if there is a semantic difference, but in the web examples to do an operation on a root note it's used `ref('/').update(...)`. (note the '/')